# Is there a way to add Custom Document Fields to an envelope document using the DocuSign SOAP API?

Tags: docusignapi

I attempted to use [CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates](https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/dsapi.asmx?op=CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates) SOAP message and included DocumentFields:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <ns1:CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates xmlns:ns1="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
      <ns1:TemplateReferences>
        <ns1:TemplateReference>
          <ns1:TemplateLocation>Server</ns1:TemplateLocation>
          <ns1:Template>BD944A97-BF86-4FA8-9BAF-EBEECD9BDCAC</ns1:Template>
          <ns1:Document>
            <ns1:ID>1</ns1:ID>
            <ns1:Name>Test Doc</ns1:Name>
            <ns1:PDFBytes>JVB...</ns1:PDFBytes>
            <ns1:DocumentFields>
              <ns1:DocumentField>
                <ns1:Name>DOC_CUSTOM_FLD_NAME</ns1:Name>
                <ns1:Value>Doc Custom Field Value</ns1:Value>
              </ns1:DocumentField>
            </ns1:DocumentFields>
          </ns1:Document>
          <ns1:RoleAssignments>
            <ns1:RoleAssignment>
              <ns1:RoleName>Applicant</ns1:RoleName>
              <ns1:RecipientID>1</ns1:RecipientID>
            </ns1:RoleAssignment>
          </ns1:RoleAssignments>
        </ns1:TemplateReference>
      </ns1:TemplateReferences>
```

But the DocumentFields were not returned on the **CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesResponse** and are not returned when making a [RequestStatusWithDocumentFields](https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/dsapi.asmx?op=RequestStatusWithDocumentFields) SOAP call:

```
<soap:Body>
  <RequestStatusWithDocumentFieldsResponse xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
    <RequestStatusWithDocumentFieldsResult>
      ...
      <DocumentStatuses>
        <DocumentStatus>
          <ID>1</ID>
          <Name>Test Doc</Name>
          <TemplateName>External Doc Test Template</TemplateName>
          <Sequence>1</Sequence>
        </DocumentStatus>
      </DocumentStatuses>
    </RequestStatusWithDocumentFieldsResult>
  </RequestStatusWithDocumentFieldsResponse>
</soap:Body>
```

Should **CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates** support DocumentFields if included?
Is the SOAP API still maintained by DocuSign?

I also looked, but was unable to find anything in the SOAP API like the "Add Custom Document Fields to an Envelope Document" found in the REST API:

```
URL:
/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/{documentId}/fields
```

I know I may have to use REST API calls to accomplish this, but would appreciate any help understanding if SOAP API can do this before I go down that path.